# Details about the BFR abort procedures?

Tags: spacex, landing, abort, spacex-starship

What kind of emergency procedures will the BFR have during landings? I can see an abort to an alternate landing zone but what about when you have a an emergency ten seconds after engine shutdown?

Comment: This is a good question, but at the moment, I think a bit premature. As in the only ones who would know the answer are SpaceX staff, and they probably are still developing most of them. I very much look forward to someone actually answering this, even if it takes a few years.  Having said that, on landing, 10 seconds after landing, you are at least on the ground.